# Does SqlBulkCopy Enlist in Ambient Transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this.  I have a SqlBulkCopy operation that is wrapped in a TransactionScope with a number of other operations.

I am aware of overloads in the SqlBulkCopy constructor that allow passing a SqlTransaction object.  Assuming I am not passing a transaction in the constructor, will the command automatically participate in the ambient transaction created by the TransactionScope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done some testing, and it appears that SqlBulkCopy does, in fact, honor an ambient transaction, at least in .Net 4.5.

To test, I did a SqlBulkCopy operation while debugging, and verified that the rows made it to the database (via a NOLOCK/dirty read query).  I then threw an exception on the next line of code, and allowed the TransactionScope to roll back.  I then verified that the rows were no longer in the database.